# passing unique session in an array to the resume viewer page and being able to return and view other results

Tags: php, unique, session-variables

I am trying to pass on a unique *jobseekerid* in the array so as to call up their unique resume information. But it’s only providing me with the same information relating to one of the fields and not changing when I go to the others. I tried session destroy but got some errors. Please help.

Resume viewer:

```
<?php
session_start();

$jobseekerid = $_SESSION['jobseekerid'];


$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("jobmerger");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM resume WHERE jobseekerid = $jobseekerid");

if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $employer_name_1a = $row['employer_name_1'];
    $employer_address_1a = $row['employer_address_1'];
    $job_1_datesa = $row['job_1_dates'];
    $job_1_titlea = $row['job_1_title'];
    $job_1_dutiesa = $row['job_1_duties'];
    $employer_name_2a = $row['employer_name_2'];
    $employer_address_2a = $row['employer_address_2'];
    $job_2_datesa = $row['job_2_dates'];
    $job_2_titlea = $row['job_2_title1'];
    $job_2_dutiesa = $row['job_2_duties'];
    $employer_name_3a = $row['employer_name_3'];
    $employer_address_3a = $row['employer_address_3'];
    $job_3_datesa = $row['job_3_dates'];
    $job_3_titlea = $row['job_3_title'];
    $job_3_dutiesa = $row['job_3_duties'];
    $employer_name_4a = $row['employer_name_4'];
    $employer_address_4a = $row['employer_address_4'];
    $job_4_datesa = $row['job_4_dates'];
    $job_4_titlea = $row['job_4_title'];
    $job_4_dutiesa = $row['job_4_duties'];
    $skillsa = $row['skills'];
    $native_languagea = $row['native_language'];
    $language_1a = $row['language_1'];
    $language_1_levela = $row['language_1_level'];
    $language_2a = $row['language_2'];
    $language_2_levela = $row['language_2_level'];
    $language_3a = $row['language_3'];
    $language_3_levela = $row['language_3_level'];
    $education_levela = $row['education_level'];
    $school_1_namea = $row['school_1_name'];
    $school_1_coursesa = $row['school_1_courses'];
    $school_1_datesa = $row['school_1_dates'];
    $school_1_degreea = $row['school_1_degree'];
    $school_2_namea = $row['school_2_name'];
    $school_2_coursesa = $row['school_2_courses'];
    $school_2_datesa = $row['school_2_dates'];
    $school_2_degreea = $row['school_2_degree'];
    $school_3_namea = $row['school_3_name'];
    $school_3_coursesa = $row['school_3_courses'];
    $school_3_datesa = $row['school_3_dates'];
    $school_3_degreea= $row['school_3_degree'];





}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>


complexsearch.php
<?php
session_start();

$jobseekerid = $_SESSION['jobseekerid'];


$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("jobmerger");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM resume WHERE jobseekerid = $jobseekerid");

if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $employer_name_1a = $row['employer_name_1'];
    $employer_address_1a = $row['employer_address_1'];
    $job_1_datesa = $row['job_1_dates'];
    $job_1_titlea = $row['job_1_title'];
    $job_1_dutiesa = $row['job_1_duties'];
    $employer_name_2a = $row['employer_name_2'];
    $employer_address_2a = $row['employer_address_2'];
    $job_2_datesa = $row['job_2_dates'];
    $job_2_titlea = $row['job_2_title1'];
    $job_2_dutiesa = $row['job_2_duties'];
    $employer_name_3a = $row['employer_name_3'];
    $employer_address_3a = $row['employer_address_3'];
    $job_3_datesa = $row['job_3_dates'];
    $job_3_titlea = $row['job_3_title'];
    $job_3_dutiesa = $row['job_3_duties'];
    $employer_name_4a = $row['employer_name_4'];
    $employer_address_4a = $row['employer_address_4'];
    $job_4_datesa = $row['job_4_dates'];
    $job_4_titlea = $row['job_4_title'];
    $job_4_dutiesa = $row['job_4_duties'];
    $skillsa = $row['skills'];
    $native_languagea = $row['native_language'];
    $language_1a = $row['language_1'];
    $language_1_levela = $row['language_1_level'];
    $language_2a = $row['language_2'];
    $language_2_levela = $row['language_2_level'];
    $language_3a = $row['language_3'];
    $language_3_levela = $row['language_3_level'];
    $education_levela = $row['education_level'];
    $school_1_namea = $row['school_1_name'];
    $school_1_coursesa = $row['school_1_courses'];
    $school_1_datesa = $row['school_1_dates'];
    $school_1_degreea = $row['school_1_degree'];
    $school_2_namea = $row['school_2_name'];
    $school_2_coursesa = $row['school_2_courses'];
    $school_2_datesa = $row['school_2_dates'];
    $school_2_degreea = $row['school_2_degree'];
    $school_3_namea = $row['school_3_name'];
    $school_3_coursesa = $row['school_3_courses'];
    $school_3_datesa = $row['school_3_dates'];
    $school_3_degreea= $row['school_3_degree'];





}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: You really don't need to assign every field in each row to its own variable, you can use it as $row['fieldName'] just fine. Also please indent all your code by four spaces so it appears as one code block.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass only jobseekerid to resumerviewer.php

echo "
        **$jobseekerid 
        $jobseekerfirstname $jobseekerlastname** 
        $jobseekeremail
        $jobseekeraddress
        $jobseekerphoneno
        
 Resume information

";

in resumerviewer.php

$run = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `jobseekers` WHERE `jobseekerid`=' . intval($_GET['id']));
if(mysql_num_rows($run))
{
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run);
   print_r($row);
}